# Swift computer property in apple documentation

Tags: getter

I am learning swift and have a question relating to {get} keyword in apple documentation.  Here is an example in the UIStoryboardSegue API reference:

```
var destination: UIViewController { get }
```

Does the {get} keyword indicate that destination is a computed property with a getter?  If so, how can I access the code for the getter to see what it is actually doing?

Answer (score 0):

You can't see the implementation of the `UIStoryboardSegue` class. UIKit is a closed source framework.

Comment: So then what does {get} mean?

Comment: It means that it's a read-only property, you can't assign anything to it.